# php 5.6 file_put_contents blank on large content

Tags: php, php-5.6

PHP 7 works fine for this but when I use 5.6 I dont get an error but `file_put_contents` just creates a blank file when inserting large content into a file.  Its just text but it can be a lot.  Is there a config setting or something I am missing?  It works fine for less content.

Thanks!

EDIT
When using fopen I get

> failed to open stream: Result too large

Theres only one other file in the directory.

Comment: Define "a lot"...

Comment: How large does it have to be to have this problem?

Comment: Maybe you're running into a 32-bit vs. 64-bit distinction?

Comment: seems to have an issue going over 600kb or so.  Other ones I tried that worked were around 210kb

Comment: 600K is nothing. What does `file_put_contents()` return?

Comment: it returns a  0  as the return

Comment: Is your v5.6 test on the same machine and running under the same userid as your v7 test?

Comment: Yes it is.  All the same.  I get the same result when running on a production server as well as local.

Comment: Can you dump the `strlen()` of your content before writing it, to make sure it's actually not empty?

Comment: strlen shows 621425

Comment: Weird. Try using `fopen()` and `fwrite()`?

Comment: So when I used fopen and fwrite I get "failed to open stream: Result too large"  which leads me to believe theres a config or something I am failing to set larger.

Comment: getting "failed to open stream: Result too large" on fopen.   The directory has one other file and the file its trying to open currently doesnt exist.  using fopen(filepath, "W");

Comment: The string "result too large" exists nowhere in the PHP source, so I'm guessing that's coming from your OS -- perhaps you have an OS-level filesystem quota. Try writing to `/tmp` instead?

Comment: Try to manually create a file that large from the shell: `openssl rand 1048576 > /path/to/file`

Comment: Why would it work fine with PHP 7 and not php 5?  Seems like a PHP issue.